# chatGPT messages not always in French, sometimes in English

Tags: chatgpt-3.5, computer-programming, api, code, internationalization

When using a rather long prompt in French, I get messages *sometimes* back in English . All of my prompts are rather similar. Has anybody experienced a similar issue ?
I am using the following code:

```
completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages=[
        {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
    ],
    temperature=0
)
```

Comment: Could you please add some examples? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen when using GPT-3 (at the time) as part of a language learning app. It seemed to pick up on the fact that the inputs were not from a native speaker, and the more noticeable that was, the more it gravitated towards switching to English.

I solved it in my application by having a lightweight ngram based check for the language and retrying.